# PostSharp Conflicting Aspects warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation, postsharp, aop

I'm using PostSharp Express in VS2013 to create validation aspects which I can apply to my properties.  I followed [this PostSharp guide on location interception](http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception).  They all work well but I am getting hundreds of warnings stating:

> Conflicting aspects on "MyNamespace.get_MyProperty": transformations
>   ".MyValidation1Attribute: Intercepted by advice OnGetValue,
>   OnSetValue" and "MyNamespace.Validation2Attribute: Intercepted by
>   advice OnGetValue, OnSetValue" are not commutative, but they are not
>   strongly ordered. Their order of execution is undeterministic.

Which I think is a result of my placing multiple validation aspects on the same properties.  First I tried to comma-separate the attributes, which I understand is supposed to order them: `[Validation1,Validation2]` but the warnings still remained.

Since my aspects are commutative (it doesn't matter which order they are executed), [the PostSharp docs advise](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/introducing-postsharp-2-0-3-aspect-dependencies) to mark them as such using AspectTypeDependency as follows:

```
[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Commute, typeof(ILocationValidationAspect))]
```

However, it appears that the `PostSharp.Aspects.Dependencies` namespace is not included under the Express license.  Is there any possible solution to resolving these warnings using only the Express license?  Or does this mean I can't ever use more than one aspect without buying pro or ultimate?  I would be willing to try to implement my own dependency controller if I could remove these warnings this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AspectTypeDependency requires Professional edition. But the AspectTypeDependency type should be included even in Express edition - there should be using non-licensed feature build time error then.

You can use AspectPriority:

```
[Validation1(AspectPriority = 1), Validation2(AspectPriority = 2)]
```

Alternatively you can assign the priority in aspect constructor. It is much less flexible than aspect ordering but at least it resolves the warning.