# Postsharp 6.0.28, .NET 4.7.1 and a weird warning while compiling

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I faced with the following warning during compilation of my project:

> 6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): warning PS0114: 
>   Conflicting aspects on "BusinessLayer.BOMnt.GetAllTimerServices(System.Nullable, System.Nullable, System.Boolean, System.Boolean, System.String, System.Nullable)": 
>   transformations "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Wrapped by advice(s) OnEntry, OnExit" and "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Wrapped by advice(s) OnEntry, OnExit" are not commutative, but they are not strongly ordered. Their order of execution is undeterministic.
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Detail of dependencies for the previous warnings: 
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker BEFORE (0):
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    (no dependency)
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker BEFORE (1):
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    (no dependency)
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Wrapped by advice(s) OnEntry, OnExit:
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    Action=Order, Position=After, Condition={equals "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker BEFORE (1)"}
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    Action=Order, Position=Before, Condition={equals "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker AFTER (1)"}
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Wrapped by advice(s) OnEntry, OnExit:
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    Action=Order, Position=After, Condition={equals "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker BEFORE (0)"}
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    Action=Order, Position=Before, Condition={equals "Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker AFTER (0)"}
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker AFTER (0):
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    (no dependency)
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: Model.Helper.MiniProfilerStepAttribute: Marker AFTER (1):
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124:    (no dependency)
>   6>C:\prj\InternalWSvc\development\BusinessLayer\BOMnt.cs(39,31,39,50): message PS0124: .

What does it mean and how to avoid its appearance in future?

Comment: We don't have your code. What other help are you seeking (that you can reasonably expect from strangers on the Internet) that the message hasn't already given you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostSharp Conflicting Aspects warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533292/postsharp-conflicting-aspects-warning)

Answer (score 2):

It means you have two instances of MiniProfilerStepAttribute on BusinessLayer.BOMnt.GetAllTimerServices.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread but maybe someone will find it useful. In my case the duplicates were caused by the aspect inheritance. More details are here
https://blog.postsharp.net/post/deeper-into-aspect-inheritance.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).